# save unique key as object in javascript in any collection

Tags: javascript

I want to save key as object in javascript so i try to use Map collection as

```
 let tempEntry = {y:y,x:x}

    let exist = map1.has(tempEntry);

    if(exist){
        map1.set(tempEntry,true)

    }else{
        map1.set(tempEntry,false)

    }
```

but it not find the key and always return exist as false..
I have list that I take also the x and y and put it in tempEntry varaible.

what I want to do is list of objects as
key:{y:y,x:x},value:true/false

is any one has other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Map#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) checks the same object reference.

If you have another object with same keys/values, you get not the original object.

```js
var x = 4,
    y = 4,
    tempEntry = { y, x },
    map1 = new Map;


map1.set(tempEntry, map1.has(tempEntry));
console.log([...map1]);

map1.set(tempEntry, map1.has(tempEntry)); // sets true
console.log([...map1]);

tempEntry = { y, x };

map1.set(tempEntry, map1.has(tempEntry)); // new object
console.log([...map1]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A possible solution, could be a serialized string of the object, if the order of the keys is the same.

```js
var x = 4,
    y = 4,
    tempEntry = JSON.stringify({ y, x }),
    map1 = new Map;

map1.set(tempEntry, map1.has(tempEntry));
console.log([...map1]);

tempEntry = JSON.stringify({ y, x });

map1.set(tempEntry, map1.has(tempEntry)); // same object
console.log([...map1]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have key value the same.. the issue is that key as object always return false

Comment: the second solution works with JSON.stringfy.. why do i need to do that way?

Comment: because the object in the first example is taken and any other object with hte same keys/values are different objects. the stringify returns a sting and does not keep an object reference.

Comment: how can I iterate on the map1 and get all the true values?. I set many objects into map1.

Comment: you could [`Map#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) and iterate all mapped items and push the wanted into the result array.